# Regex Nan error number only

Tags: javascript, regex, nan

I have an HTML form with input = "text". I need this to be text and not number.

On the javascript side, I try to remove the nonnumerical character which works only if the first thing I type is a number. If I type a letter first, I will get a NaN error. And yes I need the parseInt as another script launches after this one. Thanks

```
function numberonly(id)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    var numbers = x.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    if (x.value.length>0)
    {
        x.value = parseInt(numbers, 10);
    }
}
```

If possible, i would avoid using the "event" option as seen here. http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php

Comment: You probably want `if(numbers.length > 0)` not `x.value`.

Comment: But do you **really** want an input of `2 and 5` to result in the value `25`?!

Comment: Your regex seems to work fine for me (in Chrome) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e2b60be/)

Comment: Hmm thanks PartyLich. Maybe its the code after that causes the error. But thats kinda weird, will check it out. 

The input really is for numbers so i dont want a space.
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">
I'm using text & pattern so its easier to type on in iphone.

Thanks georg, didn't notice that. But thats not the problem. I have another script running similary and got the .length correctly.

WIll update when i need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Problem solved. It was the parseInt giving an error. I think it is parsing what blank means.

SOLUTION:

```
var x = document.getElementById(id);
var numbers = x.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
if (numbers.length>0)
{
    x.value = parseInt(numbers, 10);
}
else
{
    x.value = "";  //0 can be used
}
```